# How to find the top 300 trending YouTube videos on a given day?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to scrape the top 300 trending YouTube videos on a given day. Problem is; on https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending too few videos are shown and there isn't a way to see more. Ideally I'd like trending videos of a day I input too.

Any ideas how I can do this? Possibly through 3rd party scrapers?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Youtube API uses the "trending" keyword. If you look at [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters), the closes thing I can find is `most Popular`:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&key=API_KEY
```